# Creating custom VoiceOver rotor to navigate UICollectionView vertically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a large square grid (225 cells) constructed as a 2d `UICollectionView` and I would like blind users to be able to navigate the grid easily. Currently they would need to scroll horizontally through every square to go down. Ideally, I'd like to have a custom VoiceOver rotor that allows for left, right, up and down swiping to navigate. Is this possible?

If not, I would settle for having a custom rotor which moves up and down via left/right swipe. I've attempted to create one by getting the current `indexPath` and using the `scrollToItem` method to change it. The rotor can be selected but has no effect currently so I've done it wrong so far.

```
private func setupVerticalRotor() -> UIAccessibilityCustomRotor {

    let vertRotorOption = UIAccessibilityCustomRotor.init(name: "Move vertically") { (predicate) -> UIAccessibilityCustomRotorItemResult? in

        let forward = predicate.searchDirection == UIAccessibilityCustomRotor.Direction.next
        let visibleCells = self.collectionView.visibleCells
        if let firstCell = visibleCells.first {
            if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: firstCell as UICollectionViewCell) {
                if forward {
                    let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section + 1)
                    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: newIndexPath, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredVertically, animated: false)

                }else {
                    let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section - 1)
                    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: newIndexPath, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredVertically, animated: false)
                }
            }
        }
        return UIAccessibilityCustomRotorItemResult.init(targetElement: self.collectionView , targetRange: nil)
    }
    return vertRotorOption
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally, I'd like to have a custom VoiceOver rotor that allows for left, right, up and down swiping to navigate. Is this possible?

The native rotor has already the item to navigate vertically.
[image]

For your code, I suggest to take a look at [this custom rotor example](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#custom-rotor) + check your collection view cells update with breakpoints in Xcode.

Comment: @peteypiper Just note that there's a whole lot of native rotor actions available, but users need to activate these to have them show up in their rotor action list.